# How to store Colors in string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, colors, rgb

I want to store Color in string if they are Human Readable format and ToArgb() if they are not.

Color is Red then store it in "Red" string and If color is say some variant of green then it is store as "ff40ff80".

At runtime I want to convert this strings back to Color class Object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck. The [`Color.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50cb8sdx.aspx) method will do this for you:

> #### Return Value
>
> Type: `System.String`
>
> A string that is the name of this Color, if the Color is created from a predefined color by using either the `FromName` method or the `FromKnownColor` method; otherwise, a string that consists of the ARGB component names and their values.

Comment: Parsing back from `System.String` to `System.Drawing.Color` can be done with `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml` (there ain't a need to use `.ToString()` you could also do `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml`)

Answer (score 8):

```
Color color = Color.Red;
string colorName = color.Name; // this gives you the ability to switch back to Color through Color.FromName()
Color sameColor = Color.FromName(colorName);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Cody Gray already said it is quite simple to get the information out of the color. The problem is getting it back into a color.

So maybe this give you some kind of starting point. It is not tested, but should you give some ideas on how to solve it.

```
public Color FromString(string name)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    KnownColor knownColor;

    if(Enum.TryParse(name, out knownColor))
    {
        return Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor);
    }

    return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(name);
}
```

I just remember that there are several problems, depending on how the color is written as string. For each exists some class within the framework but they are splitted all around the namespaces (like `ColorTranslator`).

Just be aware if you simply call `Color.FromName(Color.FromArgb(3,4,5,6).ToString())` you'll get out a color with a name, but the argb values are all zero!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solutions mentioned didn't work robustly in going from Color to string and back to Color.  They depended on whether the color was pre-defined and had a name.  The following code worked for me.

To go from Color to string:

```
string ConvertColorToString(Color color)
{
    return Convert.ToString(color.ToArgb())
}
```

To go from string to Color:

```
Color ConvertStringToColor(string s)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(s))
}
```

By converting color to a 32-bit ARGB integer representation, color semantics are preserved during the conversions.