# How to change color of button From one form to another with SQlite in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

Everyone, I have two **forms** 1st is **MainForm** and 2nd is **DropdownUserControl** *(user control)* now what I want is that when I click **SaveButton** it should save all the **parameters**
*(Alldropdown and textBoxes)* into the database, and change button colour of **Confirm** from red to green, and also retrieve that colour from the database to the **confirm** button.

EVERY THING IS WORKING FINE BUT I COULD'NT FIND TO SAVE COLOR *which is in* **MainForm** TO DATABASE AND SHOW that color to **Confirm** Button *which is in the DropdownUserControl*.

I tried but could not find any solution. Thanks in advance.

[image: LEFT IS USER CONTROL & RIGHT IS MAIN FORM OPTIONS]

**Here is the code for saving parameters Click method of** *SAVE Button*

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(AppSetting.ConnectionString()))
{

    string commandString = "INSERT INTO Information ( [DropDownButtonsNumbers], [Market], [SubMarket], [BackLay],[@BetType],[TickoffSet], [FillorKill] ) VALUES ( @DropDownButtonsNumbers, @Market, @SubMarket,@BackLay, @BetType, @TickoffSet,@FillorKill)";
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(commandString, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DropDownButtonsNumbers", ButtonComboBox.GetItemText(ButtonComboBox.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Market", MarketComboBox.GetItemText(MarketComboBox.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMarket", SubMarketComboBox.GetItemText(SubMarketComboBox.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BackLay", BackLayComboBox.GetItemText(BackLayComboBox.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BetType", BetTypeComboBox.GetItemText(BetTypeComboBox.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TickoffSet", TickOffsetTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FillorKill", FillorKillTextBox.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully", "validation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

**To retrive Data I have used the folowing code**

```
public void ShowDataInLabelsForRecordOne()
{

    using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(AppSetting.ConnectionString()))
    {
        string commandString = "SELECT DropDownButtonsNumbers, Market,SubMarket,BackLay,BetType,TickoffSet,FillorKill  FROM  InformationOfParameters WHERE DropDownButtonsNumbers=1";

        c.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(commandString, c))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    // ButtonComboBox.DisplayMember = "DropDownButtonsNumbers";
                    MarketComboBox.DisplayMember = "Market";
                    SubMarketComboBox.DisplayMember = "SubMarket";
                    BackLayComboBox.DisplayMember = "BackLay";
                    BetTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "BetType";

                    TickOffsetTextBox.Text = rdr["TickoffSet"].ToString();
                    FillorKillTextBox.Text = rdr["FillorKill"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833127/how-to-store-colors-in-string

Comment: Since you have changed button color of Confirm from red to green, why did you still want to save the color to database? Is there a field in the database to store colors? Why not save the color "green" to database via "Click method of SAVE Button"? Besides, where is "Confirm Button which is in the DropdownUserControl"? Do you want to change all "Confirm"s color? Or if you want to change a specific one, how did you distinguish them?

Comment: Thank you @KyleWang for reaching out to my request. So basically You are able to select a button on the drop-down.
When you save the parameters. The parameters will save to that button selected. Once saved to that button selected, the selected button (on the right side) will change colour. It will change from red to green. This is to show that the parameters have changed and saved.

Comment: @KyleWang Please Help me I just need 4 lines to code that will solve my problem but I can't understand.

Comment: @ZeeshanRehman OK. Are 10 independent usercontrols included in MainForm? How did you create them? Could you provide the related code? And I don't quite understand your last comment. What is 4 lines to code?

Comment: @KyleWang Thanks for your positive response, 4 lines of code means I thing 4 lines of code will resolve my problem.        Well, sir, the left-hand side is the user control form, which is placed to the **Main Form**  And on the Right-hand side is  The actual Main form which includes the Edit confirm, buttons with some tex. Now, I want to click on the save button and all data must be saved and transfers the green color to the Confirm button.

Comment: confirm button color should be changed when I click the Save Button. on user control. Means want to pass the color value from user control to the Mainform's Confirm Button.    And then i want to save and retrieve that button color from the database. I must be able to see the green color to the confirm button. when i close and open the application i find see same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the controls on the right-side are? Your custom controls? Or 3rd-party controls? I assumed that they are custom controls.

Here is a demo maybe you can refer to.

I have created the user control(***DropdownUserControl***):

[image]

And another user control(***AnotherUserControl***):

[image]

To get the "Confirm button" instance, we need to define a property in `AnotherUserControl.cs`.

```
public partial class AnotherUserControl : UserControl
{
    public AnotherUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Show some text
    [Description("Test text displayed in the textbox"), Category("Data")]
    public string label1text
    {
        get => label1.Text;
        set => label1.Text = value;
    }

    // Show Button Id 1-30
    [Description("ID"), Category("Data")]
    public string labelID
    {
        get => label2.Text;
        set => label2.Text = value;
    }

    // Get Confirm button instance
    public Button BTN
    {
        get => btnConfirm;
        set => btnConfirm = value;
    }
}
```

Then modify the `btnSave_Click` in `DropdownUserControl.cs`.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form1 is the Main Form in your description 
    Form1 form1 = this.Parent as Form1;
    foreach (Control control in form1.Controls)
    {
        //  Check if is AnotherUserControl and the button ID
        if (control is AnotherUserControl && ((AnotherUserControl)control).labelID == comboBoxbutton.Text)
        {
            AnotherUserControl uc = control as AnotherUserControl;
            uc.BTN.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0); // change Confirm button color to green
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I added the DropdownUserControl and four AnotherUserControls. And here is the test result.

[image]

As to save the color to database and retrieve it, you can save the rgb value as a string in to datatable, such as `"0,128,0"`.

Then subscribe to `Form_Load` event. Similar to the code in "btnSave_Click", Judge whether it is AnotherUserControl, check the buttonID, and query the database to get the corresponding "rgb string".